# Is there something like a unique_ptr without a default constructor?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

When using unique_ptr, it is easy to forget to initialize the pointer, which may lead to a crash at runtime.

Why is unique_ptr defined with a default constructor leaving it pointing to nullptr? If it had always required a constructor parameter, the programmer would be forced to put it in the initializer list. Okay, if the default constructor is useful, wouldn't it also be useful with some kind of valid_unique_ptr that requires a constructor argument?

Should I subclass unique_ptr to force initialization, or maybe wrapping would be the way to go?

I'm a bit surprised I can't find this suggested or done anywhere...

Example:

```
#include "XTimerFactory.h"

struct MyClass {
  MyClass(XTimerFactory& timerFactory)
    : m_timer(timerFactory.createTimer()) // <- Crucial, or program will crash later
  { }
  void start() { m_timer->start(100); }
private:
  std::unique_ptr<XTimer> m_timer;
}
```

Comment: `std::make_unique<T>(constructor args)` will guarantee a pointer to T unless it throws, can make use of `if(u_ptr)` which checks if the ptr is nullptr or not.

Comment: the error is in your class not in the calling code. Such mistakes you would typically catch by writing tests.

Comment: In the same way as any other types which have default initialization when you require/want specific value.

Comment: Inheriting from `unique_ptr` will not ensure that `unique_ptr` is not released/moved out/re-assigned. You probably want another type of smart pointer

Comment: I gather that you are expecting `unique_ptr` to be more like a **reference** which *must* refer to an object, rather than a **pointer** which *may* refer to an object, or *may* be `nullptr`.  The benefit of `unique_ptr` over a raw pointer is that it won't be uninitialized.  And — unless there are shenanigans (*technical term*) — it won't be a dangling pointer either.  It'll either point to a valid object, that it owns, or it will be `nullptr`.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is unique_ptr defined with a default constructor leaving it pointing to nullptr?

`unique_ptr` models a pointer that is unique - not a pointer that always points to something. A default constructor (nullptr initialization) allows the class to be used in a lot more scenarios than a constructor always pointing to a valid instance.

For example, when you put unique pointers in a vector, it allows for a safe and easy implementation of the `vector::resize` operation.

> Should I subclass unique_ptr to force initialization, or maybe wrapping would be the way to go?

As a general rule, if the class doesn't have a virtual destructor, consider wrapping instead of subclassing it.

> I'm a bit surprised I can't find this suggested or done anywhere...

Also see [std::reference_wrapper](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) and [std::ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) - though these do not take ownership.

Here's an implementation of something similar I did a while ago (shameless plug :D): https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/54371/polymorphic-owned-reference-wrapper-for-class-hierarchies

Comment: Generally, I DO want the smart pointer to take ownership, just also require an explicit constructor parameter...

Comment: Then the best idea would be to wrap `unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is unique_ptr defined with a default constructor leaving it pointing to nullptr?

Probably because default constructible types are generally useful and convenient.

> Should I subclass unique_ptr to force initialization, or maybe wrapping would be the way to go?

Both should work.

Answer (score 1):

> When using unique_ptr, it is easy to forget to initialize the pointer, which may lead to a crash at runtime.

That is why you stick to `auto uFoo = std::make_unikue<Foo>();` (since C++14).
This way your new variable will always be valid. Using a default constructor or a costructor that takes a raw pointer is useful when ownership is passed from some other than `std::unqiue_ptr` object. So there will be no way to use `std::make_unique`, otherwise always stick to it.

Moreover, `std::unqie_ptr` by design may be `nullptr` since there are `release` and `operator bool`, which would have no sence otherwise.

Comment: More fundamentally, we can _move_ a `std::unique_ptr`, which necessitates an empty state.